# Hide php link if the field is empty?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to display a link only if it has a value.

How can i get the image if the_field imdb is not empty?

```
<a href="<?php the_field('imdb'); ?>" >
  <img style="width:60px;"src="/img/link.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i didnt want to show the img or link on older posts i solved it by:

```
<?php 

// assign image
$imdbimg = "<img src='http://mydomain.com/IMDb.png' class='imdb' />";

// imdb link from custom field
$imdblink = get_field('imdb');

?>

// display img and link on post newer then id 16
<?php global $post;
if ( $post->ID >= 16 ){  
echo '<a href="' . $imdblink . '" target="_blank"> ' . $imdbimg . '</a>';
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_field();` instead of `the_filed();`.

```
if(!empty(get_field("fildname"))){
#your code hear
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
if(!empty(the_field('imdb'))){
    <a href="<?php the_field('imdb'); ?>" ><img style="width:60px;"src="/img/link.png" /></a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(isset(the_field('imdb'))&&!empty(the_field('imdb'))){
<img src=""/>
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `isset()` from the `empty()` docs `empty is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false`.